# Considerations for calling out to enterprise applications behind a firewall from salesforce?

Tags: security, callout, bestpractice, certification, architecture

If I'm looking to integrate an enterprise application behind a firewall with Salesforce, what considerations should I be making?

From the architect certification study guide

> Given a scenario, describe the considerations when working in an environment that requires a call from an external application to an enterprise application behind a firewall.

Digging through the documentation and technical libraries on developer force and don't find much on this topic. Let's fill the gap with a great answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enable salesforce to access enterprise applications behind a firewall, you will have to expose the system to outside network. It comes with associated security concerns and usually requires enterprise security reviews and approvals from security team.

Exposing applications to external world is usually done through security gateways like Layer 7. Such gateways do not expose the actual application end point to external world, instead they expose a middle layer end point. Then calls to these gateways are further secured using CA signed/self signed certificates in the http request.Only if the request is ensured as genuine using certificates, it will be forwarded to actual internal end point

Comment: +1 with some additions:

- Create a two way SSL Auth by generating a cert in the instance and having the internal application side require it for communicating with the service in addition to having the gateway secured as well.

- Limit IP Ranges on the gateway side to only allow Salesforce IPs

- Add an additional parameter to the internal call such as an Org ID

-Using the "middle layer" gateway allows you to keep the actual web call to the enterprise service within the firewall.